# How to pass an array to chart.js data:[] while creating a chart in php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, chart.js

I have this array $data_dispensed, when I `print_r()` it, I get

```
Array (
  [0] => 270.00
  [1] => 22956.00 
  [2] => 23655.00 
  [3] => 27418.00 
  [4] => 2295820.50 
  [5] => 114476.00 
  [6] => 312220.00 
  [7] => 26580.00 
  [8] => 12680.00 
  [9] => 6300.00
)
```

which is okay

Now when I pass the array to `data:[]` in `chart.js`

---

```
data: [<?php echo join($data_dispensed,',')?>]
```

---

it displays the bar chart but the hover option doesn't work anymore, how can I solve this, and when I hardcode the variables and hover, the columns actually display the data

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't storing the data with JS rather than echoing the array through php into a JS Array?

Comment: have you tried using `json_encode` to convert the array?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code..

```
data: [<?php $s2 = array();
foreach ($data_dispensed as $value)
$s2[] = round($value);
echo implode(',',$s2); ?>]
```